# How to create custom validation rules in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I am trying to create a custom validation rule in laravel 5.3. In **AppServiceProvider** I have extended Validator like this

```
Validator::extend('image64',function ($attribute,$value,$parameters,$validator){
        $type = explode(',',$value)[0];
        if (stripos($type, "image/jpeg") !== false || stripos($type, "image/jpg") !== false || stripos($type, "image/jpeg") !== false) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

and inside **validation.php**

```
'custom' => [
    'base64' => 'The :attribute must be an jpeg/jpg/png',
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],
```

and I am using it like this in my controller.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:industries',
            'image' => 'required|base64'
        ]);
```

but i am getting error

```
"Method [validateBase64] does not exist."
```

Comment: I think you've used the wrong name, `Validator::extend('image64'` versus `'image' => 'required|base64'`. Image64 Vs Base64.

Comment: @KirkBeard Great thanks! That was the actual mistake. Good night bro